# How to filter data in the mat table based on the value obtained from ngx mat select search

Tags: angular-material-7, angular-material-table

I have two components one is my app component and the other component is my multiple mat select search component in which i used ngx mat select search  Iam passing the selected value using event emitter to app component. My angular material version is 7.3.7 and mat select search version is 1.7.1

Comment: could you paste the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-omyu1h-juy4ay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html     this is th elink which i followed for ngx-mat-select-search

Comment: in my app.component.ts i have the following which captures the value selcted in select component         
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
 
  
  selectionChanged(values: string) {
    console.log('Selection changed', values);

    }
and in app.component.html i have a angular material table of version 7  @Esteban Gehring

Comment: there is no `@Output selectionChanged` in your child component. moreover, could you please add a table to show how you use it? do you want to use the search keyword entered in the ngx-mat-select-search or the option selected in the mat-select?

Comment: I have added the @output in my child component as // 3. output whenever a change is made to selectedValues
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();

Comment: i want the option selected in the mat select to be used for filtering the table ,I don't know where to place this selected value so that the table gets filtered based on that @EstebanGehring